# Assign TextBox text to TextBlock - System.NullReferenceException: „Object reference not set ..."

Tags: c#, reference, uwp, textbox, textblock

C# UWP Application XAML (Body Mass Index Calculator - BMI)

I need to take `TextBox txtKG.Text`and pass it to `txtDescription.Text`

I'm assuming that i have to create instance of TextBox Class somehow but I'm stuck on this error for 2 days. I have tried many ways but I don't know exackly what to do.

ERROR MESSAGE:

**System.NullReferenceException: „Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”**

MY XAML segment:

```
<Slider x:Name="sldKG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,306,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Minimum="40" Maximum="150" Value="70"/>

<TextBox x:Name="txtKG" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,310,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=sldKG,Path=Value}"/>

<TextBlock FontSize="18" x:Name="kg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,316,0,0" Text="kg" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Slider x:Name="sldCM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Minimum="145" Maximum="240" Value="170"/>

<TextBlock FontSize="18" x:Name="txtDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,499,0,0" Text="Type Your parameters and i wil show Your BMI" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="96" Width="302" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

MyPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Kalkulator_BMI_UWP
{   
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page  
    {            
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
txtDescription.Text = txtKG.Text;   // <!-- HERE IS THIS ERROR
       }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the Slider value changed event, an error occurs since the controls have NOT yet been loaded (TextBlocks in your XAML),
and as a workaround (which I do in some of my projects), you can encapsulate the method with a try-catch statement like this:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       txtDescription.Text = txtKG.Text;
   }
   catch { }
}
```

Comment: It'd be better to register the Slider_ValueChanged event in the Page's Loaded event after the controls have loaded.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. Thanks to you, I can finally finish this application and publish it in the Windows Store. I wish you a wonderful day.

Comment: @KselosMax You can mark as answered if it did help you and have a good day

Comment: what's the app called? I'll have a look ;)